# How do I prevent the feed aggregator creates blank nodes when cron is run?

Tags: 6, nodes, cron, feeds

I've recently taken over the management and development of a Drupal 6 site and one of the problems plaguing this installation is that blank nodes authored by "Visitor" keep popping up.

[image: screenshot]

I've narrowed the issue down to the RSS aggregator and it seems like the nodes are being created when this runs durring the cron job. Has anyone seen this before? If so how do I go about fixing this? If not, does anyone have an idea where to look in order to resolve this?

Comment: Which modules are installed on the site? Aggregator, the module that Drupal comes with, doesn't create nodes from the aggregated content. You can see it in action on Drupal.org: http://drupal.org/aggregator.

Comment: There are a slew of modules installed, some custom, some from drupal.org.  I'm no longer sure the problem is with the RSS aggregator, I see a log entry of `action 05/17/2011 - 9:11am Saved  <my_username>` that I think is related to this issue thogh.

Comment: For sure there is a module that creates nodes, but creates them in the wrong way. You can see the nodes that result posted by "Visitor" don't have a title, nor a correct content type; both are empty, in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) module. It creates blank nodes if you have some crappy nodes in scheduler table.